# Given $v \in V$ and $dim(V) = 1$, show that exists a subspace $U$ of $V$ where the orthogonal projection of $v$ is equal to $\alpha$

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been asked to prove or disprove the following:

Given $v \in V$ and $dim(V) = 1$, show that exists a subspace $U$ of $V$ such that the length of the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto that subspace is equal to $\alpha$ and that $0 \leq \alpha \leq \|v\|$.

How does one approach this question?

Comment: Subspaces of a 1-dimensional space are either $\{0\}$ or the space itself.

Comment: @ndhanson3 How does it affect it?

Comment: How does what affect what?

Comment: @ndhanson3 My question..?

Comment: The only options for the subspace $U$ are $\{0\}$ or $V$ itself. Do either of these satisfy the condition in the question?

Answer (score 0):

That question is weird, since it is a property of the orthogonal projection that the norm of a point's image is no larger than the norm of said point, regardless of the subspace on which it is projected. So it's not only possible to find a subspace $U$ that satisfy your conditions, but every possible subspace works, regardless of $V$'s dimension. But let's assume you are not supposed to know that.

Then, let's check what happens for the simplest value of $U$ you can think of. Namely, $\{0\}$ looks simple enough. The projection of $v$ on $U$ belongs to $U$, therefore it is $0$. Therefore, $\alpha=0$ satisfy the $0 \leq \alpha \leq ||v||$.

Comment: I suspect that the intended question is something like this: Let E be a vector space, V be a subspace of E of dimension 1 an v $\in$ V. For every $\alpha$ such that $0\leq \alpha \leq ||v||$, show that there is a subspace U of E of dimension 1 such that the orthogonal projection of v on U is of norm $\alpha$.

Comment: "Smaller" is not a good choice of word, since it invites the misinterpretation of "strictly less than". If you want to stay away from the mathematical lingo ('"less than or equal"), then you should say "no larger than" instead of "smaller than".